# Assembly program that identifies if parameters are different or same.

Tags: function, assembly, low-level, hla

Hi I am working on an assembly, technically HLA(High Level Assembly) assignment and I am a bug that I need help with. Here is the assignment:                         
*Write an HLA Assembly language program that implements a function which correctly identifies whether all the parameters are different, returning either 0 or 1 in EAX depending on whether this condition has been met. This function should have the following signature:*

procedure allDifferent( x: int16; y : int16; z : int16 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;

Shown below is a sample program dialogue.

Feed Me X: 205
Feed Me Y: 170
Feed Me Z: 91
allDifferent returns true!

Feed Me X: 0
Feed Me Y: 0
Feed Me Z: 0
allDifferent returns false!

Feed Me X: 121
Feed Me Y: 121
Feed Me Z: 121
allDifferent returns false!

Here is the code I have. My problem is that regardless of what numbers I put in, it always returns "allDifferent returns false!" Thanks you for the help.

```
program allDifferent;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );
static
iDataValue1 : int16 := 0;
iDataValue2 : int16 := 0;
iDataValue3 : int16 := 0;
iDataValue4 : int16 := 0;


procedure allDiff( x: int16; y : int16; z : int16 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
static
returnAddress : dword;
temp : int16;

begin allDiff;
pop(returnAddress);
pop(z);
pop(y);
pop(x);
pop(temp);

push(returnAddress);
push(AX);
push(BX);

mov(x, AX);
cmp(y, AX);
je xyequal;
jmp notequal;

xyequal:
mov(y, BX);
cmp(z, BX);
je equal;
jmp notequal;

equal:
mov(0, EAX);
jmp ExitSequence;

notequal:
mov(1, EAX);
jmp ExitSequence;


ExitSequence:
pop(BX);
pop(AX);
ret();
end allDiff;

begin allDifferent;
stdout.put( "Gimme a X:" );
stdin.get( iDataValue1 );
stdout.put("Gimme a Y:");
stdin.get(iDataValue2);
stdout.put("Gimme a Z:");
stdin.get(iDataValue3);

push( iDataValue1 );
push( iDataValue2 );
push( iDataValue3 );
push( iDataValue4 );
call allDiff;

cmp(EAX, 1);
je ISDIFFERENT;
jmp NOTDIFFERENT;


ISDIFFERENT:
    stdout.put("allDifferent retursn true",nl);
    jmp EndProgram;

NOTDIFFERENT:
    stdout.put("allDifferent retursn false",nl);
    jmp EndProgram;

stdout.newln();

EndProgram:


end allDifferent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notequal:
mov(1, EAX);         <<- good.
jmp ExitSequence;
:
ExitSequence:
pop(BX);
pop(AX);             <<- not so good.
ret();
```

Have a close look at what's happening to `AX` in the above sequence. Even though you set it to something within the code, you *overwrite* that value with the `pop` instruction, reverting `AX` to whatever it was when you entered the function.

Assembler functions should generally preserve and restore registers that may be being used by the callers, but *not* when you want to use that register to return some useful piece of information.

---

In addition, your parameters are not being treated correctly. You push them in the order `{p1, p2, p3, junk}` (not sure why you have a fourth parameter since you don't use it for anything).

But, within the function, you pop in the order `{x, y, z, temp}`. Now, because the stack is a LIFO (last in, first out) structure, the mappings will be:

```
junk -> x
p3   -> y
p2   -> z
p1   -> temp
```

That means the `x` variable will be set to some arbitrary value rather than one of the "real" parameters you passed in.

If you're not going to *use* that fourth parameter, I'd suggest getting rid of it. If you *do* want to use it at some point, you'll need to correlate your push and pop operations so you get the correct values.

---

As an aside, you could probably also make your code a lot cleaner in a couple of ways.

First, there's no real need to use (or save/restore) `BX` since `AX` is used locally (in a small `mov/cmp` block). You could use `AX` both for the `xy` check and the `yz` check.

Second, you could get rid of quite a few of the jumps that aren't actually needed. The pseudo-code for your algorithm can boil down to a very simple:

```
    if x and y are same, go to NOTDIFF.
    if y and z are same, go to NOTDIFF.
DIFF:
    set AX to 1
    go to END
NOTDIFF:
    set AX to 0
END:
    return
```

Comment: Ok, so when you say we preserve and restore the registers only when it is used by the callers. By callers you mean anyone calling the function correct? So let's say I was recursively calling allDifferent. That would be a situation where I would want to preserve and restore the registers?

Comment: @Elijah: Yes, though it's probably a bit complex introducing recursion in to the mix. Let's just say a good general rule is that functions should document what they destroy (like scratch data and registers) and what they use to return useful info. Everything else, they should leave as is (or preserve-on-entry/restore-on exit).

Comment: So I removed the popping and pushing of AX and BX, but it is still not working correctly. If I put 0 for all three parameters it returns false as it should, but if I put something like 121 for all three parameters, it actually returns true. Is there something else I needed to change?

Comment: @Elijah, ah yes, the "fourth parameter" problem :-) Have a look at my update, it's because your pushes and pops don't match up (in terms of the order, the *quantity* is fine).

Comment: Ok I'm glad you brought up me using that junk "temp" variable. The reason I used it is because I saw my teacher use it when he had a function with one 16bit parameter. He then used a temp variable with 16 bits because he said it has to be 32 bit aligned. I was just thinking that if I have three 16bit parameters, then I need a temp 16 to make sure it evens out to 32. I'm wrong about that though?

Comment: @Elijah, no idea, it would depend on the underlying architecture. I'd try without it for a start since it just clutters the code. If you have to put it back in, put it back in.

Comment: Yea, it actually works fine without that junk variable. I have a question, this is apparently HLA not "real" assembly, but what differences do you see from this code from actual assembly? I don't see anything high level about it.

Comment: Procedure definiitions, variable definitvions, etc. It's still pretty low level but that's probably why it's high level assembly rather than high level language.

Comment: Ok I see. Well the program works, thanks for all the help.